# __box: identifier not found

Tags: visual-c++, c++-cli

I think '__box': identifier deprecated in VS 2015 compiler. What is the alternative for that?

```
#using <mscorlib.dll>
using namespace System;
using System::Collections::Stack;

int main() {
   Stack* pS = new Stack();
   Int32 i = 5;       
   pS->Push( __box(i) );
}
```

[MSDN about _box](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d6d8ft9s(v=vs.71).aspx)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Support for `/clr:oldsyntax` is removed in Visual Studio 2015 (the old syntax has been deprecated since Visual Studio 2005).  See ["Compiler Switch Deprecation/Removal Changes in Visual Studio '14'."](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vcblog/archive/2014/06/13/compiler-switch-deprecation-removal-changes-in-visual-studio-14.aspx)

Old-syntax Managed C++ source code must be ported to C++/CLI.  E.g.,

```
Stack^ pS = gcnew Stack();
Int32 i = 5;
pS->Push(i);
```

Answer (score 1):

There is [implicit boxing](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c53ss7ze.aspx) now.

> The Visual C++ compiler now boxes value types to Object. This is
>   possible because of a compiler-defined conversion to convert value
>   types to Object. Boxing and unboxing enable value types to be treated
>   as objects. Value types, including both struct types and built-in
>   types such as int, can be converted to and from the type Object. Compiler option: /clr

Code from [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d16cd479.aspx):

```
// clr_implicit_boxing_Std_conversion.cpp
// compile with: /clr
int f3(int ^ i) {   // requires boxing
   return 1;
}

int f3(char c) {   // no boxing required, standard conversion
   return 2;
}

int main() {
   int i = 5;
   System::Console::WriteLine(f3(i));
}
```

Comment: @JamesMcNellis here you go.